# Copy-Assignment Operator of class uses (copy and swap) and ordinary implement give different result

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, copy-and-swap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;


class Has_ptr {
public:
    friend void swap(Has_ptr &lhs, Has_ptr &rhs);
    friend bool operator<(const Has_ptr &a, const Has_ptr &b);

    
    // constructor
    Has_ptr(const std::string &s, int num) : ptr(new std::string(s)), i(num) {}

    // copy constructor
    Has_ptr(const Has_ptr &a) : ptr(new std::string(*a.ptr)), i(a.i) {}


    // copy-assign operator
    /*
    Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr tmp) 
    {
        this->swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }
    */

    /*
    Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp) 
    {
        std::string *x = new std::string(*(tmp.ptr));
        delete ptr;
        ptr = x;
        i = tmp.i;
        return *this;
    }
    */

    

    // destructor
    ~Has_ptr() {
        delete ptr;
    }
    
    void swap(Has_ptr &rhs) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(ptr, rhs.ptr);
        swap(i, rhs.i);
    }
    
    void print() {
        cout << *ptr << i;
    }
private:
    std::string *ptr;
    int i;
};


// add a swap function
void swap(Has_ptr &lhs, Has_ptr &rhs) {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}


bool operator<(const Has_ptr &a, const Has_ptr &b) {
    return a.i < b.i;
}
```

In C++ Primer 5th,13.3 Swap, exercise 13.31. The question require give the class **Has_ptr** a < operator and create a vector with few element then sort the vector. The implementation of class is above.

**Has_ptr** that have 2 data member

1. string pointer **ptr**, point to dynamic memory
2. int i

**Has_pt**r class have following copy-control member

1. constructor takes a string and an int.
2. copy_constructor, implemented as the class act like value.
3. destructor that delete the dynamic memory allocated by **ptr**.

I have attempt two implementation for the copy-assign operator.
One I first create temp string pointer variable x to save the RHS pointer, then delete LHS pointer and finally assign the RHS to LHS. However, this implementation makes the code unable to compiler.

```
Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp) 
{
    std::string *x = new std::string(*(tmp.ptr));
    delete ptr;
    ptr = x;
    i = tmp.i;
    return *this;
}
```

The second implementation used copy and swap. This makes code compiler and run fragmentally.

```
// copy and swap
Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr tmp) 
{
    this->swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

My main function is the following

```
int main() {
    Has_ptr a("a", 0), b("b", 1), c("c", 2);
    a.print();
    vector<Has_ptr> coll{a, b, c};

    std::sort(coll.begin(), coll.end());

    for (auto h : coll) 
        h.print();
}
```

The second implementation produce no error/warning message while compiler and produce following output

```
a0a0
```

The first implementation produce following error message

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,             

    from 13_31.c++:9:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1882:25:   required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1968:31:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4707:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >]'
13_31.c++:88:39:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1849:17: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Has_ptr&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<Has_ptr&>::type {aka Has_ptr}'
        *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);
                 ^
13_31.c++:42:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Has_ptr& Has_ptr::operator=(Has_ptr&)'
     Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp)
              ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:61:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from 13_31.c++:9:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__pop_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1672:19:   required from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1930:25:   required from 'void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1945:27:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Size = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1965:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4707:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >]'
13_31.c++:88:39:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:246:17: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Has_ptr&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<Has_ptr&>::type {aka Has_ptr}'
       *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
                 ^
13_31.c++:42:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Has_ptr& Has_ptr::operator=(Has_ptr&)'
     Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp)
              ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:61:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from 13_31.c++:9:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Distance = int; _Tp = Has_ptr; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:335:22:   required from 'void std::__make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1669:23:   required from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1930:25:   required from 'void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1945:27:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Size = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1965:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4707:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >]'
13_31.c++:88:39:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:220:29: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Has_ptr&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<Has_ptr&>::type {aka Has_ptr}'  
    *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first + __secondChild));
                             ^
13_31.c++:42:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Has_ptr& Has_ptr::operator=(Has_ptr&)'
     Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp)
              ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:61:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from 13_31.c++:9:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_heap.h:226:29: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Has_ptr&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<Has_ptr&>::type {aka Has_ptr}'
    *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first
                             ^
13_31.c++:42:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Has_ptr& Has_ptr::operator=(Has_ptr&)'
     Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp)
              ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from 13_31.c++:6:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'static _BI2 std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = Has_ptr*; _BI2 = Has_ptr*]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:588:58:   required from '_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true; _BI1 = Has_ptr*; _BI2 = Has_ptr*]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:598:5:   required from '_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true; _BI1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _BI2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:668:48:   required from '_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _BI2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1848:8:   required from 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1882:25:   required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:1968:31:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4707:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Has_ptr*, std::vector<Has_ptr> >]'
13_31.c++:88:39:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:548:18: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Has_ptr&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<Has_ptr&>::type {aka Has_ptr}'
      *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
13_31.c++:42:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Has_ptr& Has_ptr::operator=(Has_ptr&)'
     Has_ptr& operator=(Has_ptr &tmp)
              ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The non-swapping copy-assignment operator should take a const reference parameter.

Comment: That solved my question XD.

Comment: Consider using std::uniqur_ptr, it is as fast and small to store as normal pointer, has smaller source code and is easier to use. E.g. it deletes automatically at the destructor or when you overwrite the pointer in the assignment operator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sebastion. I should use smart_pointer in real scenario. This is an exercise from the book.